# Need help with a military aircraft ID

Tags: aircraft-identification, us-air-force

I found this photo going through some of my mom's pictures.  I would like to know what type of aircraft this is.  I believe they flew from he UK, possibly to Scott AFB or perhaps Griffis AFB.  Time period I estimate at 1958.  Any help appreciated!

Thank you[image]

Answer (score 10):

C-121. Military version of the Lockheed Constellation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_C-121_Constellation